# parsing json data in API url using jsonparser

Tags: java, json

I have a `JSON` data in this `URL` : http://api.pemiluapi.org/calonpresiden/api/caleg/jk?apiKey=56513c05217f73e6be82d5542368ae4f

when I try parsing using this jsonparser code :

```
    package percobaan;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String makeHttpRequest(String url, String method) {
        return this.makeHttpRequest(url, method, null);
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public String makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } else if (method == "GET") {
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                // DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new
                // DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        // return JSON String
        return json;

    }
}
```

why the output just says :

```
{"data":[]}
```

this is my code :

```
package percobaan;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author nafian
 */
public class Coba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> daftar_d = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        String link_url = "http://api.pemiluapi.org/calonpresiden/api/caleg/jk?apiKey=56513c05217f73e6be82d5542368ae4f";
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String parsing = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(link_url, "POST",
                params);

        System.out.print(parsing);
//        try {
//            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(parsing).getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("results");
//            JSONArray caleg = json.getJSONArray("caleg");
//
//            for (int i = 0; i < caleg.length(); i++) {
//                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                JSONObject ar = caleg.getJSONObject(i);
//                String nama = ar.getString("nama");
//                String calon = ar.getString("role");
//
//                JSONArray riwayat = ar.getJSONArray("riwayat_pendidikan");
//                for (int j = 0; j < riwayat.length(); j++) {
//                    JSONObject ringkasan = riwayat.getJSONObject(j);
//                    String ringkasan_p = ringkasan.getString("ringkasan");
//                    map.put("pendidikan_r", ringkasan_p);
//                }
//
//                map.put("nama", nama);
//                map.put("calon", calon);
//                daftar_d.add(map);
//
//            }
//        } catch (JSONException ex) {
//            ex.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        for (int i = 0; i < daftar_d.size(); i++) {
//
//            System.out.println(daftar_d.get(i).get("pendidikan_r").toString());
//        }

    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this a string equality check `method == "POST"`? It should be `method .equals("POST")`

Comment: Have you tried with `GET` request as well?

Comment: i have tried, the output says :
WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}

Comment: There are two issues 1) POST -HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 2) GET -  Authentication error. Check the service provided by this URL. Or Try one thing hit this URL in browser, save the JSON string in File locally and try to test with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use JSON-SIMPLE, it will literally simplify your life.
https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Here is a small example for the given URL.
Please note that's I'm using Jersey for establishing the connection, but you can pretty much use anything you like instead.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

...

```
String callString = "http://api.pemiluapi.org/calonpresiden/api/caleg/jk?apiKey=56513c05217f73e6be82d5542368ae4f";

Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(callString);

ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
if (clientResponse.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed"+ clientResponse.toString());
}

JSONObject resObj = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(clientResponse.getEntity(String.class));
JSONObject data_obj = (JSONObject) resObj.get("data");
JSONObject results_obj = (JSONObject) data_obj.get("results");
JSONArray caleg_array = (JSONArray) results_obj.get("caleg");
```

Comment: awesome, your code running perfectly, thanks @thedp :)

Comment: Just a small note for future references. It's quite possible the reason nothing worked, is the lack of "application/json" in your question code.